# ForeverJS bash script errors on first line

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-ec2, npm, forever

Im trying to get a foreverJS script to run a Node server on an EC2 instance.  The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
forever stopall
forever hakuna-matata store in appropriate logs start 'full/qualified path'
```

Even if I add an `echo "getting here"` statement as the first line I still get an error.  I do not know bash scripting well, so it may be permissions, relative/absolute path, EC2/node, environment variable related, but I honestly do not know.

Stacktrace:

```
[ec2-user@12-34-56 folder]$ forever startup.sh
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
/home/user/var/www/folder/startup.sh:2
echo "gh"
     ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

I also tried via running the script via the forever service script with `forever start startup.sh` and get the same error.  I've launched from the parent direct and with a (qualified) path.

whoami - user
which forever - /usr/local/bin/forever
which npm - /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo whomai - root
sudo which npm - /usr/bin/npm
sudo which forever - /usr/bin/forever
node -v -v8.2.1
npm -v - 5.3.0

Ask if you need additional environmental information...

Comment: Wouldn't you run this like `bash ./startup.sh`?

Comment: @stdunbar I've run it before using the forever syntax - Options
  $ forever --help
  usage: forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]      https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Answer (score 3):

Forever assumes `SCRIPT` is a JS file that can be executed with Node.js You're trying to run a bash script instead, so it errors out since `echo "getting here"` obviously isn't valid JS code.

To fix this, you need to use the `-c` command line option when running `forever`. From [the docs](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever#command-line-usage):

```
-c  COMMAND      COMMAND to execute (defaults to node)
```

So in your case, you'd set `-c` to `/bin/bash`; like this:

```
forever start [LOG OPTIONS] -c /bin/bash path/to/your-shell-script.sh
```